# Why figure and oembed tags are not working?

Tags: html, ckeditor, figure, oembed

Given the following `html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <h2>Header</h2>

  <figure>
    <oembed url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7km4EHgkQiw&amp;list=RDQK-Z1K67uaA&amp;index=9"></oembed>
  </figure>

</body>

</html>
```

Why the page is not showing the youtube video?

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title of the document</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
      <h2>Header</h2>
    
      <figure>
        <oembed url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7km4EHgkQiw&amp;list=RDQK-Z1K67uaA&amp;index=9"></oembed>
      </figure>
    
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

The body code was generated by `CKEditor` (I just removed the class "media" from the `figure` tag). You can see my original post here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57320194/ckeditor-5-showing-video-element-but-plain-html-inserted-in-a-div-does-not-show)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The figure and oembed tags are not going to work to show a preview. In order to make it work I had to convert the youtube links to embeddable links and add them with an iframe.

To do so I used the solution proposed in this thread: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21607808/convert-a-youtube-video-url-to-embed-code/21607897)

```
function getId(url) {
    var regExp = /^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=)([^#\&\?]*).*/;
    var match = url.match(regExp);

    if (match && match[2].length == 11) {
        return match[2];
    } else {
        return 'error';
    }
}

var videoId = getId('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zbYf5_S7oJo');

var iframeMarkup = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/' 
    + videoId + '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
```

Comment: Another option is to use the raw HTML embedding in ckeditor and paste the code generated by YouTube in the 'share' menu of the video. This is a no-code solution if you can't add this Javascript.

Answer (score 15):

Solution tested for **CKeditor 5**

Save the exact view showing in CKeditor into DB use the below code

```
mediaEmbed: {
    previewsInData:true
},
```

Full JS Code

```
var KTCkeditorDocument = function () {
    // Private functions
    var demo = function () {
        ClassicEditor
            .create( document.querySelector( '#kt-editor' ),{
                    mediaEmbed: {
                        previewsInData:true
                    },
                }
             )
            .then( editor => {
                // console.log( editor );
            } )
            .catch( error => {
                // console.error( error );
                Swal.fire("Info !", error, "error");
            } );
    }

    return {
        // public functions
        init: function() {
            demo();
        }
    };
}();

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    KTCkeditorDocument.init();
});
```

For more details you can check this link: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/media-embed.html

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit old, but I always struggle with getting CKEditor answers for React:

Add this config to the CKEditor component:

```
config={{
   mediaEmbed: {
       previewsInData: true
   }
}
```