# How to display HTML content with Embedded video content in React? | CKEditor

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ckeditor

I used `CKEditor` to write content and embedded videos from Admin panel.

Now, I want to display `HTML` contents with embedded videos to react front side.

**What working?**

Currently all `HTML` contents are displaying correctly with

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:DOMPurify.sanitize(HTMLDATA)}}></div>
```

but video content are not displaying.
`HTML` for`VIDEO`

```
<figure class=\"media\"><oembed url=\"https://vimeo.com/643169446\"></oembed></figure>
```

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I found a partial [answer to our problem in a different question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64772319/10826693).

> You need to update your [CKEditor configuration](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/media-embed.html#configuration) for the [`Media embed` plugin](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/media-embed.html). By setting `previewsInData` to `true` the produced HTML is functionally equivalent to what you see in the CKEditor at design time.
>
> Include the following line in the [configuration](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/media-embed.html#configuration).
>
> ```js
> mediaEmbed: { previewsInData: true }
> ```
>
> If this is not what you are looking for then you need to transform the output either server side or client side as the produced HTML from CKEditor only [produces semantic output](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/media-embed.html#displaying-embedded-media-on-your-website). The CKEditor documentation recommends using a tools including [Iframely](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/media-embed.html#iframely) or [Embedly](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/media-embed.html#embedly) to do this but you can do it any way you wish.

Additionally, you must enable the iframe tag for the DOMPurify according to the [README](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify/blob/main/README.md) there.

The fix for your case is this:

```html
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:DOMPurify.sanitize(HTMLDATA, { ADD_TAGS: ['iframe'] })}}></div>
```

In my case of Next v13:

```js
sanitize(html, { ADD_TAGS: ['iframe'] })
```

Hope this helps!